# Passing user ids through a url to access a specific one?

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I am trying to make a link on my homepage where clicking it will take you to the current logged in profile, specified via user ids. I am building it off of the cakephp blog tutorial and am just trying to expand on what I already have.

The link I am using currently is:

```
<a href="/blogtest/users/view/<?php echo $user['User']['id']; ?>">go</a>
```

This link is located on my `index.ctp` file. With the full link above, I am given this error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/View/Posts/index.ctp, line 4]">go
```

However, if I shorten my link to:

```
<a href="/blogtest/users/view/<?php echo $user; ?>">go</a>
```

and don't pass any parameters, it will take me to the correct url sans the id number at the end to find the user.

This is the class I have set up to create Users:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );
```

Am I missing something within here? Do I need to tell my `index.ctp` what file it should be taking code from, using the `App::uses('','');` function? Any help is appreciated.

Also, I realize this is probably an extremely php-noob question but I can't seem to figure out an answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `$user->id`, let's see if it works.

Comment: @Akar `Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/View/Posts/index.ctp, line 4]`

Comment: Where does that `$user` variable come from?

Comment: I was messing around with my `view.ctp` trying to get it to show profiles and used `<?php
pr($user);
echo $user['User']['id'];


?>` to echo out all of the user data as a test.

I am able to link to *that* page using this link, but only on `view.ctp`
<a href="/blogtest/users/view/<?php echo $user['User']['id']; ?>">go</a>

Comment: What is the view variable you are setting in your controller to access the user data?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja it is defined with `$user = ['User']['id'];` in my `UsersController.php` file.

The link is: `<a href="/blogtest/users/view/<?php $user; ?>">go</a>` in my `View.ctp` file.

Comment: @user4875251 the error message you show in your question looks to be generated by a View template relating to the PostsController not the UsersController. What variables are you setting for the action you are looking at? If you're setting an integer `$user` variable you won't be able to treat it as an array in your View.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja How would I go about defining the `$user`? is it just `$user = ['User']['id']` ?  Should I define it in my `index.ctp`?

Comment: @user4875251 View variables need setting in the Controller using `$this->set()`. It sounds like you might be jumping in at the deep end before you've learnt to swim a bit. There's a pretty detailed explanation of setting variables in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#setting-view-variables.

Comment: I've looked through their book countless times, all of their examples are if you know what the var should be. ie: `$this->set('color', 'pink');` so they know they wanted pink, so they set it as that. How can I do it so it pulls the `id` dynamically? `$this->set('user', 'id');` ?